# SQLite prepared statements alternative for escaping

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, sql-injection

I have implemented an SQLite database on a BlackBerry mobile device. My problem is that the BlackBerry API is very limited, and does not offer prepared statements.  Therefore, I am unable to (easily) escape the SQL to prevent against SQL injection.  Does anyone have any alternatives?  Unfortunately, REGEX is not available to me either...

Do I basically need to do a replaceAll() for all special characters?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am surprised at your assertion that there are no prepared statements supported for SQLite on Blackberry, given that a tiny amount of googling and link following leads me to [this example](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/8682/CS_creating_a_parameterized_SQLite_insert_810921_11.jsp) which shows *exactly* how to do a prepared statement with positional parameters.

Comment: Oh wow, I am surprised as well. I did a lot of Googling and found nothing. I guess my search criteria wasn't good enough. Thanks for finding that!

Comment: Umm, it was top link of 'blackberry sqlite' search, followed by the 'examples' link on the sidebar and picking the obviously right one on that page. Pretty much the first thing I tried. :-)